# How to draw own route using polyline between two location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to make polyline between two locations in android so I want to put there my own route. I have many pair of latitude and longitude for one route I want to store it in one list and using this list I want to Draw polyline which follows latitude and longitude stored in the list.

can anybody please tell me the code how can I do that.

what should I use for store latitude and longitude for Example HashMap or ArrayList

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-polyline-and-markers-along-the-tapped-positions-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-arraylist/ try this

Comment: Specifically, the `PolylineOptions` (which is used to add points to a polyline) takes a `Iterable` or a parameterized sequence of LatLngs.  Both a `HashMap` and `ArrayList` can provide an `Iterable`, but the `HashMap` order (using entrySet e.g.) is not defined so that is of no use for defining a polyline.  So while any `Collection` can satisfy the API (since it implements `Iterable`), a known order is necessary to be useful for polyline - go with any `List` (which therefore has a defined order) (such as `ArrayList`) will be best.